# Apache2 : Xampp is not running

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, localhost, xampp

I have apache2 and Xampp both installed in my server now my problem is

When i stop apache2 from `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop`

and tried restart xampp like `/opt/lampp/lampp restart` i am getting the response

```
Stopping XAMPP for Linux 1.7.3a...
XAMPP: XAMPP-Apache is not running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-MySQL is not running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-ProFTPD is not running.
XAMPP stopped.
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.3a...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Another FTP daemon is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

But i am unable to access mylocalhost when i am trying this

```
/opt/lampp/lampp status
```

Each time i am getting

```
Version: XAMPP for Linux 1.7.3a
Apache is not running.
MySQL is not running.
ProFTPD is not running.
```

Please tell me what might wrong with my xampp ?

Comment: Does the apache process appear in the `ps fax` command list? If yes you might have to use `kill` to shut it down manually before you can start it again.

And check your error logs. There might be something in there.

Comment: you are using linux or windows ?

Comment: I am using linux (ubuntu)

Comment: you can check if a program is blocking the http port with `sudo netstat -nlp |grep 80`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider  CHECK UPDATED

Comment: There it is .. nginx is blocking the port. You can do the same to check if ports 21 (default FTP) and 3306 (default mysqld) are in use

Comment: Have you checked the logs ? Can you post the errors you see in the log files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`
2. Search the "Listen 80" and change it to some other port (e.g. Listen 2145)  (Line No. 40)
3. Open the file `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`
4. Search the "Listen 443" and change it to some other port (e.g. Listen 16443) (Line No. 39)
5. Open the file `/opt/lampp/lampp`
6. Search for the port "testport 80" and replace it to "testport 2145". Also change the "testport 443" to "testport 16443". (Happens to be the Line No. 197, 214)
7. Now go and run `/opt/lampp/lampp start`. (It should work now).

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that you're using xampp. Don't do that, just use the apache/mysql/whatever packages provided by Ubuntu, there's absolutely *no* need to use xampp on any modern linux distro. So remove xampp and your problems will go away. And as a side benefit you also get security updates so your server doesn't get compromised within a week.